# React onClick event firing one click too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, use-state

I have a component set up to show photos of all the players with accounts. The component is then rendered in the parent component with a onClick event handler. The problem is the onClick event is firing one click too late. So on the first click no changes are made to the state and only when I click again on the same player the state changes. If i click on the next player the state will stil record the previous player. Below is the snippets of my code responsible for that component.

Below is the setup for the component.

```
const PlayerPhotos = ({ profiles, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className='playerPhotosRow'>
      <ul>
        {profiles.map((e) => (
          <li key={e.email}>
            <img src={e.photoURL} onClick={onClick} id={e.email}></img>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};`

const PlayerLoadChart = ({ profiles }) => {
  const [emailSelect, setEmailSelect] = useState('');

  const HandleClick = (e) => {
    setEmailSelect(e.target.id);
  };

  return (
    <div>{<PlayerPhotos profiles={profiles} onClick={HandleClick} />}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just reproduced your code with some improvements. No issues so far.

```js
const PlayerPhotos = ({profiles, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <div className='playerPhotosRow'>
      <ul>
        {profiles.map((profile) => (
          <li key={profile.email}>
            <img
              id={profile.email}
              src={profile.photoURL}
              onClick={onClick}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const PlayerLoadChart = ({ profiles }) => {
  const [emailSelect, setEmailSelect] = React.useState('');

  const onClickHandler = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setEmailSelect(e.target.id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{'Email: '}{emailSelect || 'none'}</h1>
      <PlayerPhotos profiles={profiles} onClick={onClickHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const profiles = [
    {
      email: 'user1@test.com',
      photoURL: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png?text=User+1'
    },
    {
      email: 'user2@test.com',
      photoURL: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png?text=User+2'
    },
    {
      email: 'user3@test.com',
      photoURL: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png?text=User+3'
    }
  ];
  
  return <PlayerLoadChart profiles={profiles} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above-given codes, I tried to reproduce the issue you mentioned but the code seems to be working fine. Here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/LeiterLutz/pen/KKmKGeo) and below is the code that utilized from yours.

And in the codepen, you may notice that when you click on the image, the related email will be logged in the console.

```
const PlayerPhotos = ({ profiles, onClick }) => {
    
    return (
      <div className='playerPhotosRow'>
        <ul>
          {profiles.map((e) => (
            <li key={e.email}>
              <img src={e.photoURL} onClick={onClick} id={e.email} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
};
  
const PlayerLoadChart = ({ profiles}) => {
    const [emailSelect, setEmailSelect] = React.useState('');
  
    const HandleClick = (e) => {
      setEmailSelect(e.target.id)
    }
  
    console.log(emailSelect);
    return (
        <div>
          {<PlayerPhotos profiles={profiles} onClick={HandleClick} />}
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => {

    const profiles = [
        {
            email: "a@a.com",
            photoURL: "https://i.insider.com/5d0019836fc92043771f7522?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
        },
        {
            email: "a@b.com",
            photoURL: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/0vSwNGIyNd3sFKdRtyqquaOcs9sC75JNkklvfvUykS952p9ZICbgwOcjXuBHaXi60_TQz3le_keQ3dOTTKzj_2ZA7twMmDV1f-Ah3PY9HhKEfHbo39eOebDc7XZ93xlB4Bte9uiHmhFg",
        },
    ]

    return <div>
        <PlayerLoadChart profiles={profiles}/>
    </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```